# AWS region data

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there any data out there or is there someone willing to share something that they may have compiled, AWS regions (all, worldwide) to country mapping based upon performance. Combined with data related to service update cadence (or which comes first) and pricing?

I looking for something like a table I have searched high and low for something that can give me the following or at least give me some data that i can start filling out. I have to believe that someone has done something similar.

| Country | Optimal Region | Region Stats |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Albainia | optimal region for Albainia | something interesting about the region |

Comment: Your question is too vague. Look at the AWS blog for info on which regions get services first, pricing is public, and you can see inter-region performance information here https://www.cloudping.co/grid

Comment: I am basically getting at - if i were to deploy a service for, as an example, users/clients in Albainia - is there a trick or formulae for choosing an optimal region based upon performance?  There are a few data centers in EU that one can choose from - is it a rule of thumb just to choose the closest one?

Comment: If you're using a CDN then you don't have to worry about getting this as exactly right.  You could provision everybody in EU one region and then use a CDN that works well for the country of the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The great thing about AWS and public cloud in general is the ability to quickly and easily try things out for yourself. Here's what I'd do in your situation.

1. Look at the published pricing information for the regions near you. If they're all the same or similar prices in each of the regions you can ignore this criteria.
2. Look at the service availability in the regions near you. If all the services you need are available in each of the regions you can ignore this criteria.
3. Create an S3 bucket in each region. Put a 10 - 100GB file in each bucket. Time how long it takes to download the file. You might like to consider latency as well.
4. Create an EC2 instance in each region. Using that instance ping and download some resources you know are hosted in Albania. You could alternatively host resources on the EC2 instances using Apache / Nginx and see which is fastest / lowest latency.

Using the results of all those tests, which should take less than a day an cost a few dollars, you will have your answer.

Or, the simple answer, is to use the closest region. That's what most people would do.

Comment: thanks - i was hopping for a nice tidy table  :) i guess i will do the work and then post it somewhere as an answer to my own question. The internet has made me lazy.

Comment: If you are representing a business you could contact the local AWS office and ask for their advice. That would be the second simplest option. The simplest option would be to use the closest region, which would probably be good enough. Another factor could be the laws in the country the data is hosted in, probably less of an issue within the EU.